# Scan debit card with sort code and account number

Tags: ios, swift, card.io

How can I scan Shortcode and account number with [card.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source) SDK? [image]

I have implement two delegate for that

```
 func userDidCancel(_ paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {
    resultLabel.text = "user canceled"
    paymentViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func userDidProvide(_ cardInfo: CardIOCreditCardInfo!, in paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {
    if let info = cardInfo {
        let str = NSString(format: "Received card info.\n Number: %@\n expiry: %02lu/%lu\n cvv: %@.", info.redactedCardNumber, info.expiryMonth, info.expiryYear, info.cvv )

        if info.cardholderName != nil{  
            str.appending("\n Name: \(info.cardholderName)")
        }

        resultLabel.text = str as String
    }

    paymentViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/20